# Deploying a javascript only single-page application with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, single-page-application

As far as I understand it, r.js has two main modes of optimizing...a single file or a whole project.

Whole project optimization, which effectively copies over the whole project into a `dist` folder, seems more suited for larger, multi-page applications.

But let's say you have single-page application, specifically a relatively small one, where you definitely want all JavaScript concatenated into one and one file (including RequireJS/almond).

How do you go about deploying this? If I had a server side language available, I suppose the server could check an environment flag and load the appropriate script tag.

But if the environment is a static web server, what should be done? Should this be handled as part of the build script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For things like this I always recommend using tools like [Rex](http://rexify.org/) or [Capistrano](http://capify.org/), which makes configuration management and deployments extremely easy, even for single-page or static applications.

I'm using Capistrano right now to deploy some applications to my servers. In the Capistrano script I define several tasks which will do the minifying/uglifying as well as the needed patches for my HTML files (actually to use the JavaScript files located at `js-built` where the optimized files are stored instead of the `js` directory).

So your deployment script for your static website uploads the newest version of it, starts the minifying process (probably with [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)) and then patches the `index.html` file in order to use the minified versions of your script.

Due to the fact that Capistrano and Rex are extremely easy to understand this isn't even much overhead and the resulting deployment script might contain about 30 lines of code at all. It's definitely worth it.